# Zebra printer connect over USB direct, is it possible to retrive the printers name under windows

Tags: c#, usb, zebra-printers

In their C# example app they give the option to connect over the USB driver or over USD direct. For the USB direct option one needs an connection string which I think is called `USB Device Path Format`. Now the example app allows you to find out the connection string.

But in my App I would like to give the user the option to select the printer with the name shown in the Windows printer settings. But I have not found an option to match the USB direct connection string to the acctuall printer shown in the printer settings.

Is it possible to retrieve the `USB Device Path Format` in c# for a printer from the `PrinterSettings`?